# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'GELUActivation' on <module 'transformers.activations' from 'C:\...transformers\activations.py'>

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I trained the ParsBERT model using HuggingFace models and saved the model as 'weights. pt' in google collab. I loaded the weights in collab and it worked fine but while I used Pycharm to load the model and see the results, the above error appeared.

**ParseBERT model**

```
    from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, TFAutoModel
    # model_name_or_path = "HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased"
    model_name_or_path = "HooshvareLab/bert-fa-zwnj-base"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
    bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
```

**My error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:.....\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\My_file\Collegue Project\bert\pycharm_exe\content\project\gui.py", line 136, in get_bot_response
    result = get_response(message=userText, model_path=model_path,
  File "C:\My_file\Collegue Project\bert\pycharm_exe\content\project\prediction.py", line 51, in get_response
    intent = get_prediction(message, model_path, df_path)
  File "C:\My_file\Collegue Project\bert\pycharm_exe\content\project\prediction.py", line 17, in get_prediction
    model = torch.load(model_path, map_location ='cpu')
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 607, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 882, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "C:.....\python\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 875, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'GELUActivation' on <module 'transformers.activations' from 'C:\\....\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\transformers\\activations.py'>
```

Version of tools in **Collab**:

Python: 3.7.13

PyTorch: 1.11.0+cu113

Transformers: 4.19.4

Version of tools in **local**:

Python: 3.9.8

Pytorch: 1.10.1+cpu

Transformers: 4.12.5

Comment: Version conflict? Compare `transformers.__version__` of both environments.

Comment: @cronoik, tool's version added.

Comment: Hi @cronoik, I changed the version of transformers in local same as Collab, but I got bunches of new errors. these errors are like errors gotten in https://stackoverflow.com/q/72590458/19322885